# PHP reporting error on wrong line

Tags: php, error-handling

I have what appears to me, to be  two identical text files, I copy and paste exactly the same (intentionally erroneous) content in them, being the following:

```
<?
//error code
$sSQL =  "SELECT error";
fakefunction();
?>
```

But I get this in tab #1 of my browser:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function fakefunction() in
/home/public_html/notes/textfileone.php on line 3
```

And I get this in tab #2 of my browser (the same browser as tab #1 is in):

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function fakefunction() in 
/home/public_html/notes/textfiletwo.php on line 4
```

Any idea why this would be happening?

Comment: `NULL` char or something like that. From where to where are you copying code? i mean editor.

Comment: Where is fakefunction() in your code ?

Comment: @Harry It doesn't exist.  The question says that.

Comment: By browser tab, you mean that you are using a single browser with two or more tabs? Or is it two different browsers?

Comment: @Giant - same browser, two different tabs

Comment: Compare `md5file` for both files

Comment: I put this in Text Wrangler on Mac and ran 'Zap Gremlins' selecting all options and whatever it did - it did fix it. The options I ticked were: Remove Non-ASCII characters, Remove Control Characters, Remove Null (ASCII 0) Characters... not sure which one of these was the culprit.

Answer (score 2):

Possibly one of them is being saved with a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) and one without? That would add one more line to the content. Your text editor might be adding it upon save, but hiding it otherwise.